# How to change application package name from code

Tags: java, android, package, manifest

I have some project named `MyApplication` and demo version called `DemoOfMyApplication`. I have a lot of classes that must be in both projects, so I want `MyApplication` and  `DemoOfMyApplication`be in the same project. For first one I can call `Main1` class and for second one `Main2`. So I'll have two applications in one.

The main thing I want is to have different icons in my device's menu for `MyProject` and `DemoOfMyProject`.I understand that these two versions must have different Application packages. SO Can I change them from code? Or is there any way for doing what I want?

Thanks

Comment: You can't change app properties in code since code does not run when you e.g. upload it to google's play store. Values have to be hardcoded inside the apk.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have read this article http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html  but I really hop that There will be some way to change application package from java code.

Comment: Changing package name at runtime probably never because that name has to be known before you install the app. Not installed = no code running that can change it.

Comment: Thanks, good notation

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the commonly needed code into a [library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) and reference that from both `MyApplication` and `DemoOfMyApplication`?

Then you can have two separate applications, with different package names. It doesn't sound like a great idea to try and cram both applications into one.